# Tensorflow error: "two variables have the same name: OptimizeLoss/beta1_power"

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, convolution

Working on a project a coworker wrote; don't understand what he did and he's out of town for a bit.  My guess would be that two of the optimizers are trying to use the same copie of "OptimizeLoss/beta1_power," but that doesn't make sense because the code was working before and how could any CNN work if this were an issue?

We're developing a CNN model in a Jupyter Notebook for use in an app.

```python
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0a28e84925b8> in <module>()
      6 train_model(X_train,            y_train,            X_val,            y_val,            vgg_model,            max_steps=10000,            optimizer_type="adam",            lr=0.001,            batch_size=128,            checkpoint_dir=checkpoint_dir,            augment_data=False,            

----> 8             reg_lambda=0.01)

     10 # evaluate model

<ipython-input-4-5353196dc790> in train_model(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, model, max_steps, optimizer_type, lr, batch_size, augment_data, reg_lambda, steps_per_train_summary, steps_per_checkpoint, steps_per_val, checkpoint_dir)
105 
106     # define saver
--> 107     saver = tf.train.Saver()
108 
109     step = 0

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in __init__(self, var_list, reshape, sharded, max_to_keep, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours, name, restore_sequentially, saver_def, builder, defer_build, allow_empty, write_version, pad_step_number, save_relative_paths, filename)
1237     self._filename = filename
1238     if not defer_build and context.in_graph_mode():
->  1239       self.build()
1240     if self.saver_def:
1241       self._check_saver_def()

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in build(self)
1246     if context.in_eager_mode():
1247       raise RuntimeError("Use save/restore instead of build in eager mode.")
->  1248     self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
1249 
1250   def _build_eager(self, checkpoint_path, build_save, build_restore):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in _build(self, checkpoint_path, build_save, build_restore)
1282           restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially,
1283           filename=checkpoint_path,
->  1284           build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
1285     elif self.saver_def and self._name:
1286       # Since self._name is used as a name_scope by builder(), we are

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in _build_internal(self, names_to_saveables, reshape, sharded, max_to_keep, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours, name, restore_sequentially, filename, build_save, build_restore)
741       raise ValueError("Graph mode needs to build save and restore together.")
742 
--> 743     saveables = self._ValidateAndSliceInputs(names_to_saveables)
744     if max_to_keep is None:
745       max_to_keep = 0

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in _ValidateAndSliceInputs(self, names_to_saveables)
594     """
595     if not isinstance(names_to_saveables, dict):
--> 596       names_to_saveables = BaseSaverBuilder.OpListToDict(names_to_saveables)
597 
598     saveables = []

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in OpListToDict(op_list, convert_variable_to_tensor)
559           if name in names_to_saveables:
560             raise ValueError("At least two variables have the same name: %s" %
--> 561                              name)
562           names_to_saveables[name] = var
563         else:

ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: OptimizeLoss/beta1_power
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by calling

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Comment: where did u put this call()? before training or before predicting using pretrained weigths?